# www links wont redirect to a no-www 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've just added the following `.htaccess` rules for a no-www `301` redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My domain `www.example.net` now perfectly redirects  to `example.net`, but when I visit any of my articles with the `www` prefix `www.example.net/2014/03/some-article/`, the redirection wont happen. I see a broken page instead.

What's the issue here and what's the solution to fix it?

`.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Show your complete `.htaccess` file and make sure you have no secondary files inside sub folders.

Comment: Sorry :) Just added the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably related to the order your rules are being placed, since your redirects are last it might not be triggering due to the previous defined rules.

Given that you will have to change your file from:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Also keep in mind you have been using 301 redirect so your browser might have been cached, kindly use a different browser to let your old browser cache be freed and also make sure to clear your cache.**